# What do I do when I'm blind?

Tags: nethack

I'm on NetHack 3.4.3, graphical interface. I am a blind female chaotic wizard. What do I do? I can't put rings on. I also can't see any monsters.

How do I play?

Answer (score 11):

There are a few ways to cure intrinsic blindness - that is, blindness not from being blindfolded, cream pies, venom or applying cursed towels.

- You can wait for it to heal - this can take a few turns if the blindness was caused by eating rotten food or being hit by a potion of blindness, but will take many hundreds of turns if you quaffed a potion of blindness. Having read cursed/difficult spellbook takes quite a bit of turns too. If you do have to wait it out, make sure you have a good amount of food.
- Apply a unicorn horn
- Invoke the Staff of Aesculapius
- Eat a carrot.
- Cast a spell of cure blindness or extra healing.
- Drink a potion of extra healing, potion of full healing or non-cursed
  potion of healing.
- Praying to your god may help, but be aware that blindness is only
  considered a minor problem.
- Astral vision does not cure blindness, but allows you to see despite it.
- Extrinsic blindness, from cream pies, venom or applying cursed
  towels, can be cured by waiting, wiping your face using the #wipe
  command, applying a noncursed towel, or prayer.
- Telepathy is very useful for dealing with blindness.
- Searching reveals whether or not there are adjacent monsters. Repeated
  search (n 50 s) will be interrupted by adjacent monsters or blindness
  going away, which is useful when waiting for sight to return.

Otherwise, you can remove whatever it is that is blindfolding you. Having a cursed blindfold or towel stuck to your face is considered a major problem, so if it is safe to pray, your god is likely to help you out of this predicament.

If you need any more help with blindness, look [here](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Blindness).

Comment: As far as I understand, nethack.wikia.com is not as complete or consistently updated as http://nethackwiki.com, so you might want to use that instead. Also, I am unfamiliar with the term "astral vision." If you are referring to the ability to see monsters when blinded, the more common term is "telepathy."

Comment: @murgatroid99 here is what Astral Vision is: http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Astral_vision

Comment: I did not know that. In that case, I think telepathy is also worth mentioning, since it is very useful for dealing with blindness. Plus, I would also suggest mentioning that searching reveals whether there are adjacent monsters, and that repeated search (n 50 s) will be interrupted by adjacent monsters or blindness going away, which is useful when waiting for sight to return.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I have added in your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One very interesting (and difficult) thing to do is to try to ascend (win the game) while being blind the entire time.  This is called Zen conduct.

While not the most difficult of the conducts, it IS one of the most annoying.  It basically involves search, move, search, move, search, attack, search, attack, search, eat, search...well you get the idea.

But if accomplished successfully, you very much deserve to brag on the newsgroup!  And if you're playing UnNethack, you can specify Zen mode and start the game wearing a cursed blindfold, regardless of what character you choose (UnNethack also makes a good many of the other conducts pretty easy, too--and it keeps track of how faithful you are to boot!).